# Continuous numbering of examples with gb4e in both main text and footnotes

Tags: linguistics, examples, gb4e

I would like to continue the numbering of the examples with gb4e from my main text in my footnotes. I guess that this has something to do with resetting the counter for \ex in footnotes, but I do not have any idea how to do this. I have included a MWE of the 'issue' below.

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
A first example:
\begin{exe}
    \ex First test
    \gll Dit is een test. \\
    this is a test \\
    \glt `This is a test.'
\end{exe}
Now a second example in the footnote\footnote{
Below you can find the second example, which restarts from 1 instead of the expected 2:
\begin{exe}
    \ex Second test
    \gll Dit is {een andere} test. \\
    this is another test \\
    \glt `This is another test.'
\end{exe}
}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It's very non-standard. A more common way is to use `\roman` numbering for the footnote examples, restarted each footnote.  See [gb4e roman enumeration format](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/284378) for how to do that.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I checked some papers a second time and you're right. I'll do it that way then! I don't know why, but a continuous numbering across the entire document initially seemed 'cleaner' somehow.